# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

```
 **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again**
       at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
       at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:730)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:941)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1359)
       at okhttp3.Dispatcher.enqueue(Dispatcher.java:129)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.enqueue(RealCall.java:78)
       at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.enqueue(OkHttpCall.java:101)
```

when app stay mode then after sometimes app will be crashed.

Comment: Are you creating new `OkHttpClient` object for each request?

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

1- set`android:largeHeap="true"` on AndroidManifest.xml

2- changed `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m` to `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m` on `gradle.properties`

3- and on build.gradle :

```
android {
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}
```